Can an iMac 5K's Display be overclocked to a higher refresh rate with the right display controller?
I was looking at iMac 5K models and found out that some people have successfully gutted them and turned them into external displays by installing a third-party display driver board, such as this one [https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005006038403601.html].
On the product page it mentions that the controller supports either 5K resolution at 60Hz or 4K resolution at up to 120Hz.
Q: Is it possible to "overclock" an iMac 5k display panel to run at at 144hz@4K?
I didn't find any results when searching online, the only results about people overclocking mac panels are from pre-2015 models. Would running at a lower resolution have any effect on this other than saturating the DisplayPort bandwidth? It's not like it's a CRT where the resolution can change depending on settings.
